# Extract links using cheerio (with puppeteer)

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, cheerio, webautomation

I am using puppeteer & cheerio and new to this.
Here is the pertinent HTML page source code snippet:

```html
<section class="descr">
  <div class="center">
    <a class="mfp-image" href="https://site.pics/store/1234/cat/img.jpg" title="Full size: 642x642" target="_blank"><img class="lazy 123" src="/assets/images/blank.gif" data-src="https://site.pics/store/1234/cat/th_img.jpg" alt="Image"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="info">JPG | 500px | 1MB 22.11.2021</div>
  <hr id='more-3948099'>
  <br>
  <div class="blockSpoiler dl-links"><span class="fixHeader" id="download-links"></span><i class="sa sa-download-spoiler pl1em"></i><span class="blockTitle pl0">Get from file storage </span></div>
  <div class="blockSpoiler-content txtleft c-dl-links"><a rel="external nofollow noopener" href="https://link1.net/file/a8eaa368334d6214a03e0e648f6e55d4/ssic4Bl4nkin.html" target="_blank">HOST1</a>
    <br><a rel="external nofollow noopener" href="https://link2.file/view/EB54B4FD06B9297/ssic4Bl4nkin" target="_blank">HOST2</a>
    <br><a rel="external nofollow noopener" href="http://www.link3.com/file/3xdhcvtkfnh4/fjJ3ssic4Bl4nkin" target="_blank">HOST3</a>
    <br><a rel="external nofollow noopener" href="https://www.link4.com/riwtuwz9vjr3" target="_blank">HOST4</a>
    <br>
  </div>
```

I need to get these links:

1. https://site.pics/store/1234/cat/img.jpg
2. https://link1.net/file/a8eaa368334d6214a03e0e648f6e55d4/ssic4Bl4nkin.html
3. https://link2.file/view/EB54B4FD06B9297/ssic4Bl4nkin
4. http://www.link3.com/file/3xdhcvtkfnh4/fjJ3ssic4Bl4nkin
5. https://www.link4.com/riwtuwz9vjr3

Please note that there could be a link5 also in some cases (not shown in this case)

I used this code in the Chrome Developer tools:

```js
document.querySelector("div.blockSpoiler-content.txtleft.c-dl-links").innerHTML
```

```js
document.querySelector("div.blockSpoiler-content.txtleft.c-dl-links").outerHTML
```

I am able to get a lot of text that includes what is needed, along with unwanted text too. I have been trying for more than just a few hours, but not able to make any more progress.

When i write code using cheerio, I do not get any useful output:

```js
const html = await page.content();
const $ = cheerio.load(html);
console.log($("div.blockSpoiler-content.txtleft.c-dl-links"));
console.log($("div.blockSpoiler-content.txtleft.c-dl-links").innerHTML);
console.log($("div.blockSpoiler-content.txtleft.c-dl-links").outerHTML);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's the point in using both Cheerio and Puppeteer? Puppeteer already has a live HTML parser and selectors; it's functionally a superset of Cheerio.

Comment: @ggorlen you've brought that up before, some people just prefer Cheerio and it has some useful functionality (such as the sizzle pseudos). Also you can evaluate things in the debugger because it's not async.

Comment: @pguardiario Yes, and I'm still not convinced. Most of the questions that use both appear low quality to me, and I doubt they're using the debugger or sizzle selectors. Seems like an [xy situation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me -- the burden of proof seems to be "why cheerio" rather than "why not cheerio". You're re-parsing the whole DOM and creating a situation where the cheerio state is out of sync with the live page. Do you have any expert references that will help me understand that (or why) this is "a thing"? I'd love to stand corrected.

Comment: @ggorlen you're doing that once vs multiple cdp trips to the browser and back. sometimes that's better, and sometimes you don't want dom updates. But mostly it's the debugger thing for me.

Answer (score 0):

This should help.

```js
const $ = cheerio.load(html);
var urls = $('a[href]').map(function() {return $(this).attr('href') || '';}).toArray();
console.log('urls', urls);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case though, using puppeteer is better:

```
let urls = await page.$$eval('a', as => as.map(a => a.href))
```